# DeadlockLoserDataAccessException while executing jdbc batchUpdate

Tags: mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, database-deadlocks

Recently i got the following exception:
`org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback;`

it came when my code was calling the following method:
`int[] org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String[] sql) throws DataAccessException`

In short, i got `DeadlockLoserDataAccessException` while executing batch jdbc queries.

Now even though it is a Runtime Exception, i decided to catch it and do a retry.

But I am not sure what happens to queries in the batch. Do all of them get rolled back? or the queries after this exception was thrown are not executed and all queries before this was executed?

Answer (score 0):

You should catch dead lock exception outside of the transaction.

If your transaction manager is set to rollback for Exception, all queries from batch will be rolled back.